# Setting UIStatusBarStyle in childViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios7, uistatusbar

I have a UIViewController with a childViewController.

The childViewController either takes up the entire screen or parts of the screens, overlaying on top of the parentViewController.

When it takes up the entire screen I would like to change the UIStatusBarStyle.

In my plist, I have added `View controller-based status bar appearance` and set it to `NO`.

In the childViewController I have the following:

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    if (self.isFullScreen) {
        return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
    } else {
        return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    }
}

-(UIStatusBarAnimation)preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation {
    return UIStatusBarAnimationFade;
}
```

When making the transition from half and fullscreen I call:

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

But my UIStatusBar does not change appearance from light to dark.

A regular call to:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
```

works fine, however but I would like to take advantage of the fact that I can match the animation duration for the change inside an animation block.

Thank you.

Comment: You should set View controller-based status bar appearance to YES for changing for using -(UIStatusBarAnimation)preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation method.

Comment: @BoranA Ah! That helped... Also needed to set the `childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle`. Add answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to YES` in the plist for using -`(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle` method.

Comment: Thanks. Just adding to the comment that I also had to set `(UIViewController*)childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle` for the `parentViewController`